# (1/1) NotFoundHttpException when verifying my email address

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am new to laravel 5.4 and I am trying to practice some laravel stuffs. I want to create a feature of email verification when the applicant sign up and verifies his/her email before the applicant can login. But when I click the link below in order to verify the email address of the applicant I encounter this error. I don't know if I messed up with my route and having a hard time to resolve this. here is the link of the to verify the email address  http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/verify/KafEACL1U3DxoprDI0aIVpAyM3DY8Q.

Here is the code in my route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'applicant', 'namespace' => 'Applicant'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@authenticate')->name('applicant.login');
    Route::post('/logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('applicant.home');
    Route::get('/signup', 'LoginController@signup')->name('applicant.signup');
    Route::post('/register_check', 'LoginController@store')->name('register_check');
    Route::resource('applications', 'ApplicationController',
         ['as' => 'applicant']);
    Route::get('/verify', 'LoginController@confirm')->name('applicant.verify');
        //secured file view only by customer-relations
    Route::get('applications/print/{application_number}', [
         'as'         => 'applicant.application-form.print',
         'uses'       => 'ApplicationController@printApplicationConfirmation',
    ]);
});
```

Heres the code in my controller:

```
public function store(CreateApplicantRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $confirmation_code = str_random(30);

        $data = array('confirmation_code'=>$confirmation_code);

        $applicants = $this->applicantRepository->create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($input['password']),
            'address' => $input['address'],
            'cellphone_no' => $input['cellphone_no'],
            'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code
        ]);

       Mail::send('applicant-dashboard.verify', compact('confirmation_code'), function($message) {
    $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'))
            ->subject('Verify your email address');
});

        Flash::message('Thanks for signing up! Please check and verify your email.');

        return redirect(url('applicant'));
    }

    public function confirm($confirmation_code)
    {
        if( ! $confirmation_code)
        {
            throw new InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
        }

        $applicant = Applicant::whereConfirmationCode($confirmation_code)->first();

        if ( ! $user)
        {
            throw new InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
        }

        $applicant->confirmed = 1;
        $applicant->confirmation_code = null;
        $applicant->save();

        Flash::message('You have successfully verified your account.');

        return Redirect::url('applicant');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your verification link from :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/verify/KafEACL1U3DxoprDI0aIVpAyM3DY8Q
```

to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/applicant/register/verify/KafEACL1U3DxoprDI0aIVpAyM3DY8Q
```

because your route is under a group with a prefix of `applicant`

also edit the verification route to look like this :

```
Route::get('/register/verify/{confirmation_code}', 'LoginController@confirm')->name('applicant.verify');
```

don't forget to use this import at the top of your controller file after the namespace line:

```
use App\Exceptions\InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
```

this is because laravel use `psr-4` autoloading, this means that the `InvalidConfirmationCodeException` exception class is under `'app/Exceptions'` folder.

Comment: I tried to change it but still ended up with the same error.

Comment: sir you forgot to add the route `register/verify` in your routes file

Comment: like this sir? Route::get('register/verify', 'LoginController@confirm')->name('applicant.verify');

Comment: Route::get('/register/verify/{confirmation_code}', 'LoginController@confirm')->name('applicant.verify');

Comment: thank you so much! Sorry I'm not good at using routes but I'm trying to improve it. But I ended up with this Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Applicant\InvalidConfirmationCodeException' not found

Comment: just import it a the top of your file like this : use App\Exceptions\InvalidConfirmationCodeException;

Comment: Sir I already imported it on the top of my file. But still not working.

Comment: the error is `App\Http\Controllers\Applicant\InvalidConfirmationCodeExcep‌​tion` not found which means it's not the right namespace for `InvalidConfirmationCodeExcep‌` check you exception class for the appropriate namespace and then use it at the top, also it may be helpfull to run `composer dump-autoload` command

Comment: It already worked! I forgot to create that InvalidConfirmationCode in my exceptions folder btw thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 2):

there is no route register/verify/{confirmation_code} in your routes file plese add it like this :

```
Route::get('register/verify/{confirmation_code}', ['as' => 'applicant.verify' => 'uses' => 'LoginController@confirm');
```